# Unserialize mySQL text field and access items individually

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have a serialized field in mySQL.
Use the following code to unserialize.
And I get the result as show.
Do not know how to individually access each "name: value".
I have to put each value in a column in a HTML table.

```
$custom_fields = unserialize($row['cdfields']);
foreach ($custom_fields as $p_key => $p_val) {
                echo "$p_key : $p_val <br>";
            };

<!--Result -->

nombre : Fernando 
formaqueja : Forma queja 2 
apellido : Rome 
fechareclamo : 16/05/2016 
modeloauto : Gol VW 2010 
patente : AAA000 
telefono : 123456 
emailcliente : email@email.com 
motivoquejaadmin : Motivo queja admin 2 
motivoquejaadminplanahorro : Motivo queja admin plan ahorro 2 
sugerencias : No hay ninguna sugerencia 
fechaevento : 16/07/2016
```

The serialized data, looks like this:

```
a:12:{s:6:"nombre";s:8:"Fernando";s:10:"formaqueja";s:13:"Forma queja 2";s:8:"apellido";s:4:"Rome";s:12:"fechareclamo";s:10:"16/05/2016";s:10:"modeloauto";s:11:"Gol VW 2010";s:7:"patente";s:6:"AAA000";s:8:"telefono";s:6:"123456";s:12:"emailcliente";s:15:"email@email.com";s:16:"motivoquejaadmin";s:20:"Motivo queja admin 2";s:26:"motivoquejaadminplanahorro";s:32:"Motivo queja admin plan ahorro 2";s:11:"sugerencias";s:25:"No hay ninguna sugerencia";s:11:"fechaevento";s:10:"16/07/2016";}
```

Comment: It's serialized. Unserialize the data with `unserialize`. http://php.net/unserialize

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 now has a JSON data type. I suggest you look at that if you have the scope to.

Comment: Yes, I read about the JSON data type, but this is a Ticket System Support already made, I can't change the way the DB is made. Thanks for your respond.

Comment: Please make clear what exactly you want to achieve. What exactly do you mean *Do not know how to individually access each "name: value"*? After you unserialize the serialized data, you can access each key like any other php array like this: `$custom_fields['nombre']`.